# Python: failed to load package on path

Tags: python, path, eccodes

I am trying to install the cfgrib using pip using the following:

```
pip3 install --user eccodes
```

This installs the eccodes package along the following path:

```
/Library/name/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
```

When I try to run my python script (see below) I get an error message telling me:

```
UserWarning: Failed to load cfgrib - most likely there is a problem accessing the ecCodes library. Try `import cfgrib` to get the full error message
```

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cfgrib

path = '/Users/name/Library/Python/3.8/bin'
fname = 'download.grib'

ds = xr.open_dataset(path+fname,engine = 'cfgrib',backend_kwargs={'indexpath':''})
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`pip install ecmwflib`

It worked for me.

Reference

- [Cannot find the ecCodes library when pip installing eccodes: https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes-python/issues/54](https://github.com/ecmwf/eccodes-python/issues/54)